# jackhenry.dev/portal not letting me register with work email

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

When I try to create a login to https://jackhenry.dev/portal/ with my work email I get a 401 from `https://jackhenry.dev/portal/oauth2callback/?state=%...`.

One of my recent x-request-ids is `6a17801cc34176c4c680910d1a8bfe3d`. Is there something my organization has to enable with the google account to get this to work?

It appears that my personal email would allow me to generate an account. Thus I think it may be something that my organization may have set.

Comment: Your personal Gmail account works but your account via your employer's G Suite / Google Workspace account doesn't work, is that the correct interpretation? We're not aware of specific settings that a Google Workspace admin would have which would restrict signing into other apps, but it's certainly possible. You'll want to discuss your company's setup with your Google Workspace admin. Out of curiosity, are you able to use Sign in with Google with *other* sites?

Comment: One possibility raised by Engineering is that your employer's Google Workspace administrator might need to allow third-party apps (or at least authorize JackHenry.Dev): https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227?hl=en